# Make PagerTabStrip with two tabs equally fit in screen

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using `ViewPager` with `PagerTabStrip`:

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"/>

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

And I would like to accomplish my tabs to look like this as Google recommends:

[image]

I have two tabs and I would like for each of them to be fixed and take 50% of the screen. I was looking through the options in XML and programmatically and can't find anything useful.

How can I accomplish that? Thank you.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip. But you can use [alternative library](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) for getting this effect, i use it in my one project and it works well. After you add the lib to your project, set `pstsShouldExpand` to true

Answer (score 2):

You should use android.support.design.widget.TabLayout instead of PagerTabStrip.